# Displaying a different value in listbox

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 application that I have a multitab form. On one of the tabs are three listboxes that requery when opened. The data is pulled via a sql passthrough query.Below is the query. The query works to pulls budgeted hours, actual hours, etc and variance. The budgeted hours equal 1 when they don't have any hours but charge time to the project.I am looking to display a 0 instead of 1.

```
strSQL = "select distinct substring(tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.Resource_Name,1,255) as [RESOURCE NAME],"
            strSQL = strSQL & " tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.ProjectStatus as [PROJECT STATUS], tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.orig_Budget as [BUDGETED HOURS], tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.FTE_used as [HOURS USED],"
            strSQL = strSQL & " tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.ETC as [ESTIMATE TO COMPLETE], tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.tot_var as [TOTAL VARIANCE TO DATE] from tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile , tbl_ProjectMaster"
            strSQL = strSQL & " where tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.Project_Request_ID = tbl_ProjectMaster.ProjectRequestID"
            strSQL = strSQL & " and tbl_ProjectMaster.ProjectMasterID = " & GetProjectMasterID() & ";"
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "x_query_Project_Staffing_Profile"
            Call CreatetmpSQLPassthrough(strSQL, "x_query_Project_Staffing_Profile")
            strSQL = "x_query_Project_Staffing_Profile"
            DoEvents
                    Me.TabCtl0.Pages(iCurrTabPage).Controls(0).RowSource = strSQL


                    List231.Requery
                    List233.Requery
                    List235.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an `IIf`:

```
strSQL = "select distinct substring(tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.Resource_Name,1,255) as [RESOURCE NAME]," & _
        " tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.ProjectStatus as [PROJECT STATUS], IIF(tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.orig_Budget=1, 0, tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.orig_Budget) as [BUDGETED HOURS], tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.FTE_used as [HOURS USED]," & _
        " tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.ETC as [ESTIMATE TO COMPLETE], tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.tot_var as [TOTAL VARIANCE TO DATE] from tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile , tbl_ProjectMaster" & _
        " where tbl_Project_Staffing_Profile.Project_Request_ID = tbl_ProjectMaster.ProjectRequestID" & _
        " and tbl_ProjectMaster.ProjectMasterID = " & GetProjectMasterID() & ";"
```

Comment: I tried this and the listbox comes up with blank values

Comment: Then this begs the question, what is `CreatetmpSQLPassthrough()` doing?  Is it creating a pass-through query to something like SQL Server?  The question's tags didn't mention anything like this.  If so, please say so and edit your question to include the appropriate tag(s).